# Issue with indexing data frames inside function

Tags: r

I'm having difficulty properly operating on my data frame inside of a function. I know I'm not indexing properly, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I want to change the levels of a factor in my data frame, like:

```
data <- data.frame(X1=c("a","b","c"))
levels(data$X1) <- c("x","y","z")
```

But I can't seem to do the same inside of my function:

```
> ex <- function(input,var){
+   levels(input$var) <- c("x","y","z")
+   return(var)
+ }
> test <- ex(data,"X1")  
Error in levels(input$var) <- c("x", "y", "z") : 
attempt to set an attribute on NULL

> ex2 <- function(input,var){
+   levels(input[,var]) <- c("x","y","z")
+   return(var)
+ }
> test2 <- ex2(data,"X1")
> test2
[1] "X1"
```

I actually don't really care if I output `var` or not -- I just returned it for illustration. I just want to know how to properly reference my data frame and columns so I can operate on them inside the function.

Comment: `try ex <- function(input, var){} `

Comment: What does that solve?

Comment: Sorry I waited to long to edit the comment and then couldn't change. I was just going to point out that you were not returning the correct item from your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that your function was looking for `data$var` instead of `data$X1`. Also, if you have a `return` it should be of the data frame not the column name if you're going to be assigning back to `data`.

There are a number of easy ways to fix this. Here's one:

```
ex <- function(input,var){
  levels(input[,colnames(test) %in% var]) <- c("x","y","z")
  return(input)
  }


test <- ex(data,"X1")  
test
```

Comment: I think you can simplify it with `levels(input[[var]]) <- `

Comment: Using [[var]] works perfectly! Would you mind explaining the difference?